# How the best technique to deal with objects inside objects without reducing performance?

Tags: oop

I have classes with many properties, which consists, in some cases, other complex classes. Not allways I'm going to use this complete schemas, but sometimes I'm doing so. What's the best practice to create an object, deal with it and then retrieve information on demand?

I'm giving an very simple example to clarify:

Supose a class `student` which is related to a class `professor`. This class is related to other classes like `classes`, `schedules`, etc. Not allways I will need to use all this information.

Ough I to mantain the professor's ID in object `student` and then load the information when I need? Should I create a property just for storing the professorID, or I create a `new` `professor` object without loading all other data into it, just storing the `ID`? Or neither? What's the best practice?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need an RDBMS rather than an OO system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading).

Comment: Yeah, I've found that I need the "lazy inicialization" to my project. But I don't know if is a good practice storing only the information relative to the ID of the object in the own object, keeping it alive through the entire parent's lifecycle then loading the whole data in an oportune moment.

Comment: Is your data stored in a relational database management system? If so then you should ideally be using an object-relational mapper to load your relational data into your objects (and to persist them back out to the database again).

Comment: In this case, if you have a student type with a professor type property in a many-to-one relationship (with the professor being the principal of the relationship) then the ORM will normally by default use lazy loading, so will only request the Id column from the database for the professor, and will only retrieve all of the mapped properties when the professor type property on student is accessed.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [lazy loading pattern](http://www.developerdotstar.com/mag/bookreviews/joyce_PEAA.html).

Answer (score 2):

**Suggestion 1**

- Does your application requires to save & load the values of the objects & properties ( also known as "to serialize" or "to persist" ) ?
- Does your application requires to have several instances of the same class ?

If the answer to this questions is true, seems you need to store your data in a D.B., as @larsmans suggest.

**Suggestion 2**

Another thing. You didn't mention what programming language are you using. In programming languages like C++, Delphi (Object Pascal), D, an object inside another object can be handled in 2 ways: as part of the object, or as a pointer to the subobject.

I suggest use pointers to objects approach, for your scenario.

In programming languages like Java, PHP, C#, VB.NET, there is this concept called references, which in practical terms, its the same as pointer to objects, so you don't need to do anything else.

Non pointer example:

```
class SubClass
{
  public: 
    int X;
    int Y;      
}; // class SubClass

class MainClass
{
  public:
    int Color;
    SubClass SubObject;

  public:
    /* constructor */ MainClass()
    {
      this.Color = 7;
      this.SubObject();
    } // /* constructor */ MainClass(...)

    /* destructor */ ~MainClass()
    {
      this.~SubObject();
      this.Color = 0;
    } // /* destructor */ MainClass(...)
}; // class MainClass

void main()
{
  MainClass* MainObject = new MainClass();
    MainObject->Color = 5;
    MainObject->SubObject.X = 19;
    MainObject->SubObject.Y = 32;
  delete MainObject();
}  // void main(...)
```

Pointer to objects example:

```
class SubClass
{
  public: 
    int X;
    int Y;      
}; // class SubClass

class MainClass
{
  public:
    int Color;
    SubClass* SubObject;

  public:
    /* constructor */ MainClass()
    {
      this.Color = 7;
      this.SubObject = new SubClass();
    } // /* constructor */ MainClass(...)

    /* destructor */ ~MainClass()
    {
      delete this.SubObject();
      this.Color = 0;
    } // /* destructor */ MainClass(...)
}; // class MainClass

void main()
{
  MainClass* MainObject = new MainClass();
    MainObject->Color = 5;
    MainObject->SubObject->X = 19;
    MainObject->SubObject->Y = 32;
  delete MainObject();
}  // void main(...)
```

Cheers.

Comment: I'm using Java. But my problem is to deal with great delays and resources consumption, because I'm working with servlets. The few queries and loadings I have to do, the best. So, loading large ammount of information from DB and keeping it in session variables is a very bad thing in my case. I'm using RDBMS, but I prefer organizing it in a MVC model and work with OO to have its benefits.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, you will need some entities joining the entities from your domain. Say, you will have a `StudentRegistry` that will hold the correspondence between the students and their professors/lecturers. This indeed resembles an RDBMS schema design, so you can refer to the [ER DB design method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_design) (obviously, you will have classes instead of tables.)